# Get Image URL from web

Tags: javascript, image, url

I am working on some JavaScript that receives the URL of a page, like fotolog;

> http://www.fotolog.com/okendo/18551692/

And I want to search in this website to get the source URL of the image and display it in my website.
I want the URL of the main image but I don't know how.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, this is called Page Scraping, and I believe you may need some server-side script to do that.

Comment: yeah, because of cross-domain issue, a script cannot access another page from another domain

Comment: @TrinhHoangNhu - You are right, but Yahoo has already overcome that problem and exposes YQL service which will do the needful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YQL to fetch the content of the site adn use XPath to pick only the specific node. This all can be done by using AjaxP call.

[Here is sample YQL](http://y.ahoo.it/aK7kS) which shows an example for the URL mentioned in your question